# How to use existing Docker Volume in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have created a new docker image. It creates a new folder `/hello`.
When I run this image as a container, I can access the container by the `docker exec -it` .. bash command and when I perform `ls` I see the `/hello` folder.

This `/hello` folder is also saved in a Docker volume container. 
So I have linked the container with an existing Docker volume. So it's persistent.

Now is my question: Is it possible to perform the following in a Dockerfile?

A new image wants to use the same volume as the previous container, and copying the `/hello` file to its own container.

Is this possible to perform in a docker file?

Comment: I do not fully understand the question. Usually you attach volumes to your Container with the -v option. You don't need anything special in your Dockerfile for this. Could you please provide a little more information on the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible in your `Dockerfile`.

You may use a running containers volumes by using the `--volumes-from` argument when you run another container with `docker run`.

Example:

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

VOLUME /hello
```

Then:

```
$ docker build -t test-image-with-volume .
$ docker run -ti --name test-image-with-volume test-image-with-volume bash
/# cd /hello
/# ls -la
total 8

drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 18 14:59 ./
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Jan 18 14:59 ../
```

Then in another terminal (while above container is still running):

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
```

Then:

```
$ docker build -t test-image-without-volume .
$ docker run -ti test-image-without-volume bash
/# cd /hello
bash: cd: /hello: No such file or directory
/# exit
$ docker run -ti --volumes-from test-image-with-volume test-image-without-volume bash
/# cd /hello
total 8

drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 18 14:59 ./
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Jan 18 14:59 ../
/# touch test
```

Then in your original terminal:

```
/# ls -la /hello
total 8

drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 18 15:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Jan 18 15:03 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan 18 15:04 test
```

And in your new terminal:

```
/# ls -la /hello
total 8

drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jan 18 15:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Jan 18 15:03 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Jan 18 15:04 test
```

You can only link volumes from one container to another while the container with the volumes is still running.